# Failed building wheel for xmlsec - mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, homebrew

I'm installing my mac on python virtualenv environment. Whenever I install requirement packages command "pip install -r requirements.txt" i got this messages.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt ----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Running setup.py clean for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
Installing collected packages: xmlsec, python3-saml, raven, scrypt, social-auth-app-django, social-auth-steemconnect, w3lib, voluptuous, ujson, toolz, steem
Running setup.py install for xmlsec ... error
Complete output from command 
/Users/leebom/Documents/workspace/lineup/backend/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/p5/385n2cr95sq16x17334vsbnr0000gq/T/pip-install-xn4yfy51/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/p5/385n2cr95sq16x17334vsbnr0000gq/T/pip-record-kpdy8vo4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/leebom/Documents/workspace/lineup/backend/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.6/xmlsec:
running install
running build
running build_ext
************************************************************************
Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed?

Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
************************************************************************
Command "/Users/leebom/Documents/workspace/lineup/backend/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/p5/385n2cr95sq16x17334vsbnr0000gq/T/pip-install-xn4yfy51/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/p5/385n2cr95sq16x17334vsbnr0000gq/T/pip-record-kpdy8vo4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/leebom/Documents/workspace/lineup/backend/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.6/xmlsec" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/p5/385n2cr95sq16x17334vsbnr0000gq/T/pip-install-xn4yfy51/xmlsec/
```

I already did the following:

- re-install/update my xocde commandline tool
- try to homebrew xmlsec packages - and result messages was it's already installed.
- also installed pkg-config, libxmlsec1-dev too.

I have almost done everything I could find on google results... but could not accomplish the intended

And here's my **requirements.txt**

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrs==17.4.0
awscli==1.15.81
boto==2.49.0
botocore==1.10.80
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
cryptography==2.2.2
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==2.0.3
django-cors-headers==2.2.0
django-filter==1.1.0
django-mysql==2.2.0
django-ratelimit==1.1.0
django-storages==1.6.6
django-test-plus==1.0.22
djangorestframework==3.8.2
docutils==0.14
dry-rest-permissions==0.1.10
ecdsa==0.13
funcy==1.10.1
future==0.16.0
futures==3.1.1
gunicorn==19.8.1
idna==2.6
isodate==0.6.0
jmespath==0.9.3
langdetect==1.0.7
lxml==4.2.1
more-itertools==4.1.0
mysqlclient==1.3.12
oauthlib==2.1.0
Pillow==5.1.0
pkgconfig==1.3.1
pluggy==0.6.0
prettytable==0.7.2
py==1.5.3
pyasn1==0.4.4
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycryptodomex==3.6.1
pyjwkest==1.4.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
pylibscrypt==1.7.1
pytest==3.5.0
pytest-django==3.1.2
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-social-auth==0.3.6
python3-openid==3.1.0
python3-saml==1.4.1
pytz==2018.3
PyYAML==3.13
raven==6.9.0
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
scrypt==0.8.6
six==1.11.0
social-auth-app-django==2.1.0
social-auth-core==1.7.0
social-auth-steemconnect==0.0.2
steem==1.0.0
toolz==0.9.0
ujson==1.35
urllib3==1.22
voluptuous==0.11.1
w3lib==1.19.0
xmlsec==1.3.3
```

Thank you.

Comment: *Could not find xmlsec1 config.* Is `xmlsec1` installed? Is it in `$PATH`? If not — add its directory to `$PATH` and rerun `pip install xmlsec`.

Answer (score 29):

Check for Libxmlsec1 and pkg-config package in your Mac

```
brew install Libxmlsec1
brew install pkg-config
pip install xmlsec
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error (though on Python 2.7), and `brew install Libxmlsec1` fixed it.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you may have to install `homebrew` before using that command: https://brew.sh/

Answer (score 4):

On Debian you'll need `libxmlsec1-dev` in case anyone comes here from a Google search. `xmlsec1` and `libxmlsec1` are not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on macOS Catalina and needed to brew install this and then it worked

```
brew install openssl xmlsec1
```

Found the information on the last comment of this [issue](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/issues/80).

Answer (score 1):

I needed:

`brew install pkg-config`